# Magento Upload Image in system.xml is not display the correct path

Tags: magento

I have created image field on admin. and I got a problem with upload_dir and base_url is not same as I set, here's my code:

```
<bankicon translate="label comment">
    <label>Bank Icon</label>
    <comment>Allowed file types: jpeg, gif, png.</comment>
    <frontend_type>Image</frontend_type>
    <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_image</backend_model>
    <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">theme</upload_dir>
    <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">theme</base_url>                         
    <sort_order>5</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</bankicon>
```

When I uploaded 
image save at : media/theme/default
but preview image is broken I check the image link is: media/default  ==> theme path is missing.

I have try
theme/default

still not working.

how can I fix this ? I would like to fix preview image to get media/theme/default

Pls help.

Comment: is image saving to right path ?? 'media/default/theme'

Comment: I think image is saving in the right place : media/theme/default

Comment: but preview image is showing media/default. missing theme/

Comment: what is the command used to preview the image? please try Mage::getBaseUrl('media'). "theme/". Mage::getStoreConfig('var name'); var name used in magento admin panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in system.xml add following

```
           <bankicon translate="label">
                <label>Bank Icon</label>
                <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
                <backend_model>mymodule/system_config_backend_image_bankicon</backend_model>
                <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">theme/default</base_url>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <comment>Allowed file types: ICO, PNG, GIF, JPEG, APNG, SVG. Not all browsers support all these formats!</comment>
            </bankicon>
```

if you see the backend model above, i created a new class for that name Bankicon

```
 class ABC_Mymodule_Model_System_Config_Backend_Image_Bankicon extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Image
 {
/**
 * The tail part of directory path for uploading
 *
 */
const UPLOAD_DIR = 'theme/default';

/**
 * Token for the root part of directory path for uploading
 *
 */
const UPLOAD_ROOT = 'media';

/**
 * Return path to directory for upload file
 *
 * @return string
 * @throw Mage_Core_Exception
 */
protected function _getUploadDir()
{
    $uploadDir = $this->_appendScopeInfo(self::UPLOAD_DIR);
    $uploadRoot = $this->_getUploadRoot(self::UPLOAD_ROOT);
    $uploadDir = $uploadRoot . '/' . $uploadDir;
    return $uploadDir;
}

/**
 * Makes a decision about whether to add info about the scope.
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function _addWhetherScopeInfo()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Getter for allowed extensions of uploaded files.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
{
    return array('ico', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'apng', 'svg');
}

/**
 * Get real media dir path
 *
 * @param  $token
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getUploadRoot($token) {
    return Mage::getBaseDir($token);
}
```

}

Comment: in case my module name is Pay, where the class file should I save at? thks

Comment: app/code/local/YourCompany/Pay/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Bankicon.php

Comment: Thk !!!! the preview image path on admin can't change, but I just put const UPLOAD_DIR = ''; follow default image path on admin. and it works. Thk so much :)

Answer (score 0):

well i am not pretty sure, but you can consider following ...

```
<upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">default/theme</upload_dir>
<base_url type="media" scope_info="1">default/theme</base_url>
```

Comment: I already try ur solution. magento created image at media\default\theme\default

Comment: but preview image still showing with media/default/xxx.gif, it is not changing follow my config :(.

Comment: ok, i do have a solution, a bit lengthy but works for sure. see another answer

Answer (score 0):

Just Do some thing like following

```html
<largeimage1 translate="label comment">
 <label>Large Image 1</label>
 <comment>Allowed file types: jpeg, gif, png.</comment>
 <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
 <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_image</backend_model>
 <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">theme</upload_dir>
 <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">theme</base_url>
 <sort_order>37</sort_order>
 <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
 <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
 <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</largeimage1>
```

Field will be created and entry into the core_config_table.
 To show somw where you can use like:

```html
echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . Mage::getStoreConfig('system_config_name/group/largeimage1');
```

Done.